# TypeError when using the query method on a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Trying to query the DataFrame for only the rows under the 'Products' column that contain the string 'Microsoft'. The string 'Microsoft' appears as a standalone cell value as well as a comma-separated value in certain cells.

Query function worked before but now it's giving TypeError:

df = df.query("Products.str.contains('Eloqua', case=False)")

Comment: df["Products"].dtype returns Object and df["Products"].isna().sum() returns 0.  Whats odd is above query worked before.  I restarted the kernel a few times without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If df["Products"].dtype returns "Object" following should do it.

```
df = df[df.Products.str.contains('Microsoft', case = False)]
```

Comment: that did it, thanks.  Still cant understand why the query failed tho.